# What's an adjective or noun that means "about the meaning of life and purpose"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, nouns, terminology, philosophy

What's an adjective or noun that means "about the meaning of life and purpose"?

*Nihilism* is the belief that life is meaningless, so we shouldn't have to burden ourselves with purpose.

*Aristotelianism* contains the belief that there can be no meaning to life other than being a good person, so the purpose of life should be to be a good person.

*Hedonism* suggests that the purpose of life is to enjoy yourself as much as you can while you can.

What can these and other philosophies be grouped under?

> Anything that suggests a purpose for our lives is ______ (or "is an example of ___")

Comment: "Teleological" means "relating to purposes to to the study of purposes," but I don't know of a word that specifically means "relating to the purpose *of life*."

Comment: So you are asking for a word that could fulfill both the role of adjective and noun? *Existential* might work for an adjective, but *existentialism*, the noun, is altogether different.

Comment: Philosophers just seem to talk about ["the meaning of life"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/life-meaning/) using that phrase. Not all theories about the meaning of life are teleological, although if you're talking about purpose that would apply.

Comment: "The meaning of life and purpose" means "the meaning of life and the meaning of purpose", the latter seeming nonsensical. Do you mean "The meaning and purpose of life"?

Comment: These and other philosophies *are* philosophies. That is what they are grouped under. Anything that suggests a purpose for our lives is an example of philosophy.

Comment: There is no hypernym specifically for the three theories that are listed in the question; the OP's expectation that there is such a hypernym seems to be based on some oversimplifying, one-sentence definitions of them (where from?). On the other hand, if the question seeks the hypernym for 'these and other philosophies', as the punchline of the question puts it, then the answer is obviously, as already pointed out, *philosophies* (or, somewhat more elegantly, *philosophical theories*).

Answer (score 1):

*Existentialism/Existentialist*.

*Existentialism* is defined as:

> a philosophical theory or approach which emphasizes the existence of the individual person as a free and responsible agent determining their own development through acts of the will.
>
> <sub>*Oxford Languages and Google*</sub>

Comment: _Existentialism_ and the studies in this area deal with the purpose of life and human existence (as well as the meaning and value of life) so it is the most fitting philosophical concept. I would suggest you to include the adjective form "existential" in your answer that fits the example sentence in the OP. _OED_ defines _existential_ as: "Of, relating to, or concerned with individual human existence, esp. as seen from the point of view of existentialism; of, relating to, or characteristic of existentialism; having, or prompted by, a keen awareness of individual freedom and responsibility."

Comment: I've just noticed that you've mentioned "existentialist" also which can be used as an adjective as well. (and a noun for a philosopher dealing with existentialism)

Comment: Existentialism is parallel to Nihilism, Aristotelianism, and Hedonism — not an umbrella for them (which is what the OP requested).

Answer (score 0):

Worldview (German, *Weltanschauung*) is a good word to describe life's meaning and purpose.

Ken Funk, a professor at Oregon State University, provided an interesting diagram in his posting, found [here](https://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/%7Efunkk/Personal/worldview.html) and duplicated below:

[image]

Granted, the concept of a worldview is Hydra-like, containing elements of epistemology, metaphysics, cosmology, teleology, theology, anthropology, and axiology, all of which are derived from a person's knowledge. Knowledge, according to Funk, consists of opinions, beliefs, and certainties. His definition of worldview is this:

*A worldview is the set of beliefs about fundamental aspects of Reality that ground and influence all one's perceiving, thinking, knowing, and doing.*

Comment: *Weltanschauung* may include an account of the meaning of (human) life, but it encompasses far more: as the term, and the quotation at the end of this answer, imply, it is a view of the **world** (universe) as a whole. It is, therefore, not 'a good word to [**specifically**] describe life's meaning and purpose'. Incidentally, as one of the answers to a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17908) about that term points out, '*Weltanschauung* is used as an English word, from the German because the English *worldview* is too vague and not comprehensive enough'.

Comment: @jsw29: Clearly, your argument is with Professor Funk. If you look closely at his diagram, I think you'd agree that the -ologies in the white rectangle include the concepts of meaning and purpose and so much more. Perhaps you are right in suggesting that "worldview" and "Weltanschauung" are not exactly synonymous, but the way in which Funk delimits and defines "worldview" sounds an awful lot like "Weltanschauung," as you define it. Don